# Is there a way to view network bandwidth consumption a la "top"?

Tags: wireless-networking, display, networking

Several people have talked about monitoring bandwidth on a per-device basis in a wireless setting; is there a way to monitor consumption on a per-process basis? Something like "top"? (and even "nice"?).

Comment: Any particular OS? It can be done per PC, not sure how it you would monitor processes on a network of PCs.

Comment: My particular interests would be in OS X and Windows

Answer (score 0):

May be you can have a look at this software [Network traffic Monitor 2.01](http://www.sharewareplaza.com/network-traffic-monitor-download_33543.html). This software shows you which processes in your machine are causing how much TCP/IP traffic and IP's.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're after is view and not control, NetLimiter ( http://www.netlimiter.com/ ) have a freeware version that can detect incoming and outgoing traffic by application for Windows boxes, each machine monitoring itself...

There's also Wireshark ( http://www.wireshark.org/ ), which will monitor pretty much the entire network from a single machine, but it does so on a packet level, which can be a bit "Information Overload" if you're not 100% sure what you're looking for.